# Writing a byte array of tags to tiff file using libTIFF

Tags: image, tiff, exif, libtiff

I was wondering, is there any way to write an array of bytes as a whole data block (a number of tags) to .tiff file using libTIFF?

As far as I know, .tiff file is not streamable due to random data block (IFD) location. But, as I may assume, data inside that block is being written in a predefined order. What I am trying to accomplish is to write the whole exif properties byte block from jpeg file to "Exif IFD" inside my tiff.

So, is there any function like TIFFSetField(), that populates the whole data block (IFD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a TIFF data block of your own, and inside that block, data are formatted with a "private" format (it is the case, if memory serves, of RichTIFFIPTC). What you *cannot* do is send several tags to the TIFF object and expect them to end up in any particular order.

I believe that Photoshop, among others, always writes a fixed length data object as a single tag, and then rewrites its innards at leisure.

Due to the fact that EXIF collection and TIFF Tag collections overlap, you cannot do this and have your tags readable by libTIFF, though:

```
[tag1],[tag2],[tag3] ---> [privateTiffLongObject] --> not re-readable
[tag1],[tag2],[tag3] ---> [Tiff2],[Tiff3],[Tiff1] --> re-readable
```

That said, what is it that you're trying to accomplish? To simply shuttle tags from a JPEG file to a TIFF file, I'd venture that `exiftool` should be enough. I have often employed a workflow like the following:

```
(image) --> exiftool --> XML --> XML parsers -->
--> exiftool --> (new image)
```

Of course, if you need to do this for a large batch of images, performances may become a problem. That issue can be tackled more easily with RAM disks and SSD devices, though.

"Hacking" the TIFF format might leave you with files that are efficiently written and correctly handled by the software tools you now have, but won't be compatible with some other tool elsewhere -- and this might be discovered after you've done *weeks* of work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess I'm going to end up with just using the TIFFSetField() function multiple times for all the exif tags.

Comment: Hacking tiff in my case isn't an option, because the file has to be properly readable by Photoshop with all the exif tags in it. And I'm limited with only the programmming mechanisms (unable to use any tools). I was trying to gain performance by writing the whole byte block as it is to EXIF IFD (cause I already have one). Sadly, turns out it would not work in that case.

Comment: I think that Photoshop preferentially reads a XMP formatted single field of its own. I'll get my notes later tonight, but you may want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not. The [documentation states](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/libtiff.html#dataplacement):

> The TIFF specification requires that all information except an 8-byte
>   header can be placed anywhere in a file. In particular, it is
>   perfectly legitimate for directory information to be written after the
>   image data itself. Consequently TIFF is inherently not suitable for
>   passing through a stream-oriented mechanism such as UNIX pipes.
>   Software that require that data be organized in a file in a particular
>   order (e.g. directory information before image data) does not
>   correctly support TIFF. libtiff provides no mechanism for controlling
>   the placement of data in a file; image data is typically written
>   before directory information.